# How to join two extracted values with xidel?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xidel

I use the following to extract two values using `xidel -e`.

- `'//input[@name="qid"]/@value[1]'`
- `"//span[@id='trueFinalResultCount']"`

But I'd like to put the two results into a TSV format.

```
result1<TAB>result2
```

Could anybody show me how to combine the above two expressions? (I tried the following. But it doesn't work.)

`'join((//input[@name="qid"]/@value[1], //span[@id='trueFinalResultCount'][1]), x:cps(9))'`

Comment: Try `string-join( ($x, $y), '&#09;')`

Comment: Could you test the solution with `xidel`? I tried `'string-join((//input[@name="qid"]/@value[1], //span[@id='trueFinalResultCount'][1]), "&#09;")'`. But I just get the first value.

Comment: Could you share your source? Also please fix your quoting. `'function("string")'` is for Unix, while `"function('string')"` is for Windows.

Comment: I don't have your data, but this works: `xidel https://google.com --xquery 'string-join(//a ! string-join(((./string(), "¡Untitled!")[. ne ""][1], @href), "&#09;"),  "&#10;")'`. This uses standard XQuery 3 to create a TSV file: one row for each link on the Google homepage, and two columns per row (separated by tab): title and URL. If you provide a URL with your data, I would be happy to provide an answer specific to your question.

Comment: I agree with Reino - your use of quotes is likely the cause of your problem. In my sample (used on macOS), notice how a single pair of single quotes (`'`) surrounds the entire query body, and inside the query body, only double quotes (`"`) are used.

Comment: @joewiz Your example query could be simplified to `--xquery '//a ! join(((text(),"¡Untitled!")[1],@href),"&#09;")'`, or `-e '[...],x:cps(9))'`.

Comment: True. I was sticking with pure XQuery.

Comment: Also, there’s no guarantee that the a elements have only one child text node.

Answer (score 2):

string-join( ($x, $y), ' ') and replace ' ' with "tab-key pressed here"

example:

```
xidel URL --xpath 'string-join((somepath1, somepath2)," ")'
```

it results into TSV